# Running CLI on influxdb@1 installed via Homebrew

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, influxdb

I have installed version 1.9 of influxdb from Homebrew on a mac. (I don’t want to use version 2.X as it would break the way another programme feeds data to influx.)

I seem to have got the db service running - but can’t start influx cli.  I have tried various permutations of instructions - with various permutations of errors coming back.

Answer (score 0):

install influxdb 1.x with `brew install influxdb@1`
then `brew install influxdb-cli`